# C# NUnit File Comparison Assert AreEqual Same Length but Fails on Offset

Tags: c#, nunit, assert

NUnit test comparing one excel file to another excel file yields the following error:

Message: Stream lengths are both 146010. Streams differ at offset 10.

Several responses state that you need to overload the Equals operator, but there are zero guides that walk you through that process.

```
FileInfo baseFile = new FileInfo(_baseFile);
FileInfo testFile = new FileInfo(_testFile);

FileStream file1 = new FileStream(_baseFile, FileMode.Open);
FileStream file2 = new FileStream(_testFile, FileMode.Open);

Assert.AreEqual(file1.Length, file2.Length);
```

I expect the test to return true when the following happens:

```
Assert.AreEqual(data in file 1, data in file 2)
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [ask] page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: Unit tests often don't have a return value.  The typical approach in NUnit is to throw and exception (which marks the test as failed).  The exception you are seeing is because the two streams that you are comparing are different, and therefore the `Assert.AreEqual` throws because the assertion failed.  The `AreEqual` is doing a byte by byte comparison of the two streams and telling you where they differ (offset 10).